# jCarouselLite Random Start Order

Tags: jquery, jcarousellite

I'm using JCarouselLite (http://www.gmarwaha.com/blog/2007/08/09/jcarousel-lite-a-jquery-plugin/) to generate a vertical scrolling "news ticker" style carousel of testimonials and everything is working perfectly, but I would like to randomize the order in which the list items are displayed.  I attempted to use the following, but it's not working:

```
if(o.random){var randomStart = Math.floor( Math.random()*tl+1 );curr = randomStart;}
```

Then Add "random: true," to the options.

Can someone please help me figure this out?
My Script is:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){   
        $(".ticker").jCarouselLite({
            auto: 10000,
            vertical: true,
    random: true,
            visible: 1
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `start` property and set it to a random number starting from 0 to the maximum number of items you have.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    var TOTAL_ITEMS = 10;
    var randNum = Math.floor(Math.random()*(TOTAL_ITEMS+1));

    $(".ticker").jCarouselLite({
        auto: 10000,
        vertical: true,
        start: randNum,
        visible: 1
    });
});
```